# What is Bigquery count logic on external tables?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, parquet

I have a question about Google Bigquery. I have some external tables on Bigquery, they read parquet files from Google Cloud Storage. I want to learn if I run a select count(1) query on my parquet external tables, does bigquery read all parquet files and then count them or can it act more logically?
I read Bigquery documents, Google says reading per tb cost is 5$ on on-demand analysis. In this case, for example, if I have 1 tb sized parquet files on gcs, and then i run "select count(1) from mytable" on bigquery, will my query's cost be 5$ or less?
I suppose that bigquery brings parquet files to itself and creates a temproray table and then queries it. But I wonder if it uses a different logic when counting.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: BigQuery can use partition on parquet files for reducing data amount during quering. This is not the case for your example. So I guess you will be billed for all file size. I prefer to query the data from an external source to a normal BigQuery table and use partition and clustering to control costs.

Comment: The cost are at $1.1 per TB and the first 300 TB are free: "Customers can read up to 300 TB of data per month at no charge" https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

Comment: Thanks for your response Samuel, i read this document, this $1.1 per tb cost is for stream read action in bq. in my case, users will read data from an external table. your first answer is more helpful for me. I guess also cost will be for all file size. Thanks.